# is Assert.AreEqual<byte[]>(one, two); comparing objects or values

Tags: c#, arrays, unit-testing

Why `T` *cannot* be a `byte[]`?
See the description at

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms243446.aspx

```
        byte[] one = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5 };
        byte[] two = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5 };

        //don't fail
        Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToBase64String(one), Convert.ToBase64String(two));
        //fail
        Assert.AreEqual<byte[]>(one, two);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are comparing that one byte array has reference equality with another byte array (i.e. that both variables point to the same array), which in this case they don't.

A better approach is to test using [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
using System.Linq;

Assert.IsTrue(one.SequenceEqual(two));
```

Comment: Or just use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`

Comment: @juhan Ah - but he didn't specify his testing framework ;-) My answer is agnostic of that. But yes, if he's suing MSTest as he appears to be, then absolutely :)

Answer (score 4):

Well,

```
  Assert.AreEqual<T>(one, two);
```

uses `T.Equals()` when comparing. And since array *doesn't override* `Equals`

```
  byte[] one = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5 };
  byte[] two = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5 };

  if (one.Equals(two))
    Console.Write("Yes");
  else
    Console.Write("No"); // <- you'll have this
```

you'll have an unexpected outcome. When `Equals` is not overriden, `Object.Equals` compares *references*, not *values*, and references of `one` and `two` are different. In case you want compare arrays' items, use `SequenceEqual`

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question in your title, the following:

`Assert.AreEqual<byte[]>(one, two);`

Will do reference compare because you are comparing two arrays.

To compare content, do as @RB. mentioned and use `SequenceEqual`.